# Get output from user typed code JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I am experimenting with [Monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html) (VSCode IDE for web). The goal is to print the output of the code the user wrote. Ex user types `console.log("123")` then I want to get the "123" as output. How can I achieve this? Any regex or similar solutions is no good. I need the actual output from the code:

```js
        const run = () => {
            const model = monaco.current.editor.getModel()
            const value = model.getValue() // Value is console.log("123")
     
            var code = new Function(value)
            var code2 = eval(value)  //logs "123"

            console.log(code) //logs ƒ anonymous({console.log("123")}
            console.log(code2) //logs undefined
            
            const output = ?
        }
    
            <MonacoEditor
                ref={monaco}
                width="800"
                height="600"
                language="javascript"
                theme="vs-dark"
                value={code}
                options={options}
                onChange={code => setCode(code)}
            />
```

How can I set the `const output` to "123" in this example?
[image]

Or just get "123" as output from this snippet

```js
var s = "console.log(123)"
alert(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = "console.log(123)"
alert(eval(s))
```

In the above scenario, the `console.log` code is executed and the logging will be done in the console, but the value in the alert will be `undefined` because the return value from the `console.log` is `undefined`. for example:

```
const val = console.log('test');
```

Here the logging is done, but the value of `val` is `undefined`. and you are using this value in the alert statement.

> To achieve what you need you can override the logging function as follows:

```
Console.prototype.log = function(text) {
   // your code
};
```

Comment: I have the same in my code, but the issue is that i need to store the 123 in a variable

Comment: I tried it but cant understand how to use it. Can you add a snippet? Got it working now.  But do i need to combine it with eval to get it to work?

Comment: @PEPEGA yes, keep using eval how you are currently using, just override the `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with default console.log function. You need to modify it. Try this

```
console.tempLog = console.log;
console.log = function(value)
{
    console.tempLog(value);
    return value;
};

const output = eval('console.log("123")');
```

Here, I created console.tempLog to avoid the recursive loop! Hope this helps!